# Should I redo an abandoned Dynamic Data project with Lightswitch?

Tags: frameworks, microsoft

I had a small project that I was doing on the side. It was basically a couple of forms linked to a DB. Access was out, because it was a specifically meant to be a web application. Being a small project I used ASP.NET Dynamic Data, but, for various reasons, the project ended before deployment. I met the client recently, and he said there was a need for it still.

I'm considering restarting the project with Dynamic Data, but I've seen some Lightswitch demos, and was suitably impressed with the BETA. I will wait for RTM if I use it, but is it a good idea to use Lightswitch to replace the Dynamic Data? The amount of work I put into the Dynamic Data site isn't really an issue.

Additional information: It's a system that tracks production in a small factory, broken down by line, machine, section and will generate reports. I would guess that the data structure will remain fairly constant over time, but that the reporting requirements will grow. The other thing is that the factory is part of a larger group, and I'm hopeful that, if this system succeeds, similar work with be forthcoming for other factories.

Comment: How comfortable are you that the requirements will NEVER CHANGE to the point of needing the additional flexibility that Dynamic Data and ASP.NET could provide?

Comment: I doubt that there will be significant changes. The factory has been running in its current configuration for at least 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

An important note here is that LightSwitch isn't actually a web app. It can be a Silverlight app that's web deployed. So if a web based approach is a requirement, then keep that in mind.

Now would LightSwitch work better than a DynamicData application? It's hard to say, play with it a while and figure out what you feel more comfortable with. Being a web developer for a long time I'd rather use DynamicData personally.